# Webpack2 + Materialize-css + Any jquery Plugin

Tags: webpack, aurelia, materialize, webpack-2

I am working with Webpack 2 after migrating from Webpack 1. Some of my jquery plugins stop working.

I am getting the following error when using materialize-css package:

> **TypeError: $(...).parallax is not a function**

It did worked before.

The way I was using it was:

```
attached(){
    $('.parallax').parallax();

    $('body').addClass('user-background');      
}

detached(){        
    $('body').removeClass('user-background');
}
```

Comment: You'll have to post the webpack.config.js. Most likely, the plugins aren't being attached to the jquery object properly.

Comment: @Quotidian please refer to my webpack.config: 

https://gist.github.com/hmarcelodn/3ca937e37e61537b5d756ce7652d1549

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfuly fixed that. The problem was the latest version of jquery@3.1.1 / hammer included in the newest aurelia-skeleton which is not working with materialize-css and its legacy jquery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things don't look right in the webpack.config

1. You have jquery imported twice: both in '`jqueryPlugings`' and '`vendor`' entries. This is fine for production(see below) where you have the `CommonsChunkPlugin`.
2. In the `CommonsChunkPlugin` you're targeting '`common`' instead of '`vendor`' and '`jqueryPlugins`'

I hope this helps

Comment: I modified the jquery stuff but the issue is still there. Now it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/hmarcelodn/3ca937e37e61537b5d756ce7652d1549